# Displaying data from multiple tables in a single

Tags: php, mysql

This is a simple php/mysql cart system. In which there are two pages with different data tables. One is `men_products` and another is `women_products`.I have made different pages to show data of both tables and both pages have their action of "add to cart." Problem comes in cart.php. I have tried to display both table data that is been added to cart but i failed to solve the query. I am providing my code. If any one can help that will be appreciated.

> Note: women.php is similar as men.php file

**Index.php**

```
session_start();
if(isset($_GET['page'])){
$pages=array("men","cart","women","prod");
if(in_array($_GET['page'],$pages)){
    $page=$_GET['page'];
}else{
    $page="prod";
}
}else{
$page="prod";
}
?>
 <?php require($page . ".php"); ?>
 <h1>Cart</h1>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Image</th>
            <th>Qty</th>
         </tr>
    <?php
    if(isset($_SESSION['cart'])){
      $sql = "SELECT men.* , women.*  FROM men_products men , women_products women WHERE men.id IN(";
            foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $id => $value){
                $sql .=$id. ",";
            }
            $sql=substr($sql,0,-1).")  OR women.id IN(";
            foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $id => $value){
                $sql .=$id. ",";
            }
            $sql=substr($sql,0,-1).") ORDER BY id ASC"; //Updated

        $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
        if(!empty($query)){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
        ?>
        <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['product_name']; ?></td>
        <td><img src="images/<?php echo $row['product_image']; ?>"></td>
         <td><?php echo $_SESSION['cart'][$row['id']]['quantity']; ?></td>
         </tr>
        <tr><td colspan="3"><a href="index.php?page=cart">Go To Cart</a>
```

**men.php**

```
     <?php
    if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action']=="add"){
    $id=intval($_GET['id']);
    if(isset($_SESSION['cart'][$id])){
        $_SESSION['cart'][$id]['quantity']++;
    }else{
        $sql_p="SELECT * FROM men_products WHERE id={$id}";

        $query_p=mysqli_query($con, $sql_p);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($query_p)!=0){
            $row_p=mysqli_fetch_array($query_p);
            $_SESSION['cart'][$row_p['id']]=array("quantity" => 1, "price" => $row_p['product_price']);
        }else{
            $message="Product ID is invalid";
        }
         }
        }
       ?>

       <?php
        if(isset($message)){
       echo "<h2>$message</h2>";    
        }
?>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Picture</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Items Price</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
    $query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM men_products ORDER BY product_name ASC");
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['product_name']; ?></td>
        <td><img src="images/<?php echo $row['product_image']; ?>" width="120px" height="120px"></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['product_desc']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo "$" . $row['product_price']; ?></td>
        <td><a href="index.php?page=men&action=add&id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">Add to Cart</a></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</table>
```

**Cart.php**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        if(!empty($_SESSION['cart'])){
        foreach($_POST['quantity'] as $key => $val){
            if($val==0){
                unset($_SESSION['cart'][$key]);
            }else{
                $_SESSION['cart'][$key]['quantity']=$val;
            }
        }
        }
    }
?>

<h1>View Cart || <a href="index.php?page=men">Men Products</a>||<a href="index.php?page=women">Women Products</a></h1>
<form method="post" action="index.php?page=cart">
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Subtotal</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM men_products  WHERE id IN("; // stuck here. What query will be used here to display both pages add to cart data
            foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $id => $value){
            $sql .=$id. ",";
            }
            $sql=substr($sql,0,-1) . ") ORDER BY id ASC";
            $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
            $totalprice=0;
            if(!empty($query)){
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
                $subtotal= $_SESSION['cart'][$row['id']]['quantity']*$row['product_price'];
                $totalprice += $subtotal;
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['product_name']; ?></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="quantity[<?php echo $row['id']; ?>]" size="6" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['cart'][$row['id']]['quantity']; ?>"> </td>
        <td><?php echo "$" .$row['product_price']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo "$" .$_SESSION['cart'][$row['id']]['quantity']*$row['product_price']. ".00"; ?></td>
    </tr>

    <?php
            }
            }else{
    ?>
            <tr><td colspan="4"><?php echo "<i>Add product to your cart."; ?></td></tr>
    <?php
            }
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">Total Price: <h1><?php echo "$" ."$totalprice". ".00"; ?></h1><td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: if the session wasn't started in Cart.php - start it. Same for men.php and women.php

Comment: @Fred-ii- it is started in both the problem comes in `cart.php`. I have edited my cart.php have a look at the comment  please

Comment: @Fred-ii-  It shows men.php data in my cart perfectly but i want to show the purchased data from women.php as well

Comment: so, copy the exact code from one file to the other and change the associated items for women. You've been given an answer below.

Comment: i have copied the same stuff with different table name in women.php. I have mentioned the problem comes in cart.php and index.php queries which shows cart data. i am confused how to select added data from both the tables

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the question correctly, you want to select data from two tables. You will then need to select both tables like so:

```
SELECT men.*, women.*
FROM men_products men, women_products women
WHERE men.id IN(...) OR women.id IN(...)
```

You will then have a result with `men.id`, `women.id` and so on, so your check if this is already in the cart has to be changed accordingly.

Comment: i write your quey in both `index.php` and `cart.php`. i.e ` $sql="SELECT men.*, women.* FROM men_products men, women_products women WHERE men.id or women.id IN (";` but now it isn't adding any thing in cart :(

Comment: i tried your code with different IN values but it failed

Comment: have a look at the index.php i have updated it with your code